# What are the current traffic and usage patterns of this site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

The new [site analytics page](https://math.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) rolled out recently. It displays interesting statistics such as traffic sources and the volume of votes over time. What's in it currently?

Comment: Woo! More useless information that we can access! :-D

Comment: It seems strange that referring visits is 69K for stackoverflow, 50K for mathoverflow, but only 3K for MSE (us). Does anyone know how these numbers are computed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer among other things.

Comment: @BillDubuque Links within the site should not count at all; they are not referrals. For example, the same data for [SO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5rvd2.png) does not have SO among referring sites. I think those are clicks meta.math -> math which are not reported with the 4th level domain "meta." for some reason.

Comment: Yes, that's one reasonable guess. But does anyone know for sure?

Comment: ...so now I actually have a reason to get to 25k rep so I can play with the page directly.  Congratulations, SE, for roping me back in.

Comment: @apnorton Yeah, but honestly I haven't looked at the page since the day I posted this. QuantCast and Data Explorer (which now has deleted post information, too) give nearly all of the data (and more, of course). The exception is the sources of traffic (search, referrals) taken from Google Analytics. But those are shown for the last month only, nothing to play with.

Answer (score 15):

Users with 25K rep can access [site analytics page](https://math.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) directly. (There is also one for [meta.math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) if you're into [meta-meta-analysis](https://xkcd.com/1447/).)

For others, I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/normalhuman/1gka1y5b/embedded/result/) with a snapshot of the current data. I plan to keep updating it without bumping this post.

Some highlights of the current data:

- 88% of site's traffic comes from search engines, 6% from a referring site, and 6% directly
- The top referring sites are Stack Overflow and MathOverflow, followed by social networks at some distance.
- The volume of posts and visits exhibits strong seasonal patterns associated with school year.
- The volume of votes is much less seasonal.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.