# How can I find statistics on number of edits on math.SE?

Tags: support, editing, statistics, data-explorer

How can I find various statistics about number of edits done on math.SE. For example, if I am interested in number of edits per day/month/year and how these numbers have evolved, number of edits done by users below 2k (i.e., the edits which go through the suggested edits review queue), number of edits of old questions compared to number of edits of new questions, number of edits of questions in a particular tag, etc.

> - Are there some stats which SE platform displays? (Similarly as, for example, I can find out a bit about reputation and upvotes from [reputation-leagues](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues) or by looking at top-users in some specific tag. And there is also some information about voting in [25k site analytics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/is-voting-on-questions-getting-harsher/22012#22012). Some of these stats are visible also for users below 25k, see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/what-are-the-current-traffic-and-usage-patterns-of-this-site/21348#21348).)
> - Are there some interesting [data explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) queries which could give me insight into things like this.

For example I read [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17403/conversation/the-900000th-edit) that: "The 900,000th edit was recently made." and "The 16 top users by number of edits made together over 10% of the edits on this site." <s>However, I do not know how that user obtained these statistics.</s> In the meantime the user who posted this said that they have these statistics from [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/419383/yearly-stats?year=2015&opt.textResults=true).

Statistics about editing were also hinted at in the [comments to another recent question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/problem-with-majority-of-people-on-se#comment88328_22501).

Comment: The Data Explorer contains this information, and those with the knowledge of how to use it can extract it. I just attempted (by which I mean that I found [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/263549/total-edits#resultSets), and I seem to see that there are 1200000 edits to answers, questions, and tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a query that gives the number of edits per month](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/428376/edits-over-time-month-by-month#graph):

[image: edits per month]

(it is adapted from the query that @mixedmath linked in the comments; it simply groups all edits by month and displays the graph). Of course the data from this month is skewed because the month is not over yet.

Comment: [The same data day-by-date is not very informative](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/428076/total-edits#graph) due to the wild variations...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the link in your answer and the link your comment are exactly the same.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've corrected it. Apparently when you "edit" a query it doesn't create a new one (and previous links to that query now point to the edited version), I should have "forked" it.